# How to get current url as an Observable

Tags: angular

By using [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html), and subscribe to its url on init, I only get empty UrlSegment[] once. Whenever I change the url it won't work.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773187/2444505  - `startWith()` operator from RxJs could be really helpful to start the router subscription immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Location` [subscribe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html#!#subscribe-anchor) method.

Comment: Does ActivatedRoute only works with an router-outlet?

Comment: This is the first line in the link that you have provided: "Contains the information about a route associated with a component loaded in an outlet"