# Angular 2 router event not firing first time?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am routing from one component to another. Once the route is done I would like to use the URL from the previous route. I have put the code below into the constuctor of the component being routed to, but it does not fire on the first route. After the first route, the function fires every time.

```
this.router.events
      .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
          console.log(e);
    });
```

If I remove the pairwise function it seems to fire on first route, however it lists only the current route, not the previous route.

```
 router.events
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e);
 });
```

My goal is to retrieve the previous route when the new component is routed to. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This really calls for a service or at least a handler in your root component.

Answer (score 32):

As I see all these solutions relay to `route.snapshot` and try to combine NavigationEnd action with it. But if you try to access the page - it is not fired with the first `NavigationEnd` by `router.events`. Also snapshot fires parent route, not a child route. so first you could use child route, but it will be also not fired as first...

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(() => this.aRoute.snapshot),
  map((route) => {
    while (route.firstChild) {
      route = route.firstChild;
    }
    return route;
  })
)
```

so BEST solution for me with first fire on **proper** current route is using `router.events` + `router.url` with one type `NavigationEnd`:

```
 this.router.events
   .pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      startWith(this.router)
   )
   .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
     // there will be first router.url - and next - router events
 })
```

Comment: Love it! Second solution helps a lot, sad, that no event gets emitted by default.

Comment: Second solution really helpful! Thanks

Comment: thanks a ton man!! I was using startWith with empty and at top, my bad.

Comment: The second solution really help me to fix the first load of my component. Thanks

Comment: okay, but why is it keep increasing the firing count.

Answer (score 13):

The answer was already given: The `NavigationEnd` event has already been raised when the component registers for it. I don't like the idea of "Dimitar Tachev" to create a workaround by proxying those events through a subject.
In my case the solution was to:

1. Let the `Component` subscribe to the `NavigationEnd` event as before.
2. Make the `Component` load the initial state from the injected `Route` object in the `ngOnInit` method.

And finally another solution is to move the subscription to the route change events into the constructor of the component.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I think moving the subscription to the constructor should be fine here and it seems like the easiest solution to me.

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same scenario and I found out that [it's too late](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11268#issuecomment-263031832) to subscribe for NavigationEnd with pairwise in the constructor of the child component.

You could subscribe to the router in your root component and share the route data through a service like the following example:

events.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteChanged } from '../models/route-changed.model';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  public routeChanged = new BehaviorSubject<RouteChanged>({ prevRoute: '/', currentRoute: '/' });

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

app.component.ts (your root component)

```
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscriptions = new Subscription();

    constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {
            this.subscriptions.add(this.router.events
                .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
                .pairwise()
                .subscribe(navigationEvents => {
                    const prevPage = <NavigationEnd>navigationEvents[0];
                    const currentPage = <NavigationEnd>navigationEvents[1];
                    this.eventsService.routeChanged.next(
                        { prevRoute: prevPage.urlAfterRedirects, currentRoute: currentPage.urlAfterRedirects });
                }));
        }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }

    ...
}
```

your-target-route.ts

```
...
constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {
    this.subscriptions.add(this.eventsService.routeChanged.subscribe((routeChanged) => {
        // use routeChanged.prevRoute and routeChanged.currentRoute here...
    }));
}
```

P.S. It's important to use a [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) or a [ReplaySubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/replaysubject.md) in the service in order to get the proper previous route event if your child component subscribes after the page load.

Answer (score 8):

**2019, this is still an issue**

Here's how to get all route changes *including* the page load route in a sub-component.

```js
  import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    // First route event on load
    this.setFromSnapshot(this.route.snapshot);
    // Subsequent events after load
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof ActivationStart))
      .subscribe((event:ActivationStart) => this.setFromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
  }

  setFromSnapshot(snapshot:ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    // Do something
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

`pairwise` emits on the second and subsequent emissions (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise)

so it's important to set initial value for example:

```
this.router.events
  .startWith(new NavigationEnd(0, '/', '/'))
  .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .pairwise()
  .subscribe((e) => {
      console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Because of the pairwise operator it would not trigger on first run, it's wating for the next value: http://rxmarbles.com/#pairwise

Comment: As I had written it's important to set startWith operator, to get it working on the first run.

Comment: The pairwise came from OP so I assume that is known. The key here is the startWith. This is the only solution I could accept.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that your component doesn't yet exist when the navigation event occurs.

Create a global service injected in `app.component.ts` and inject it into your component too.

Create 'helper' observables on the service.

```
// RouterEventsService.ts 
navigationStart$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationStart => e instanceof NavigationStart));
navigationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd));

lastNavigationEnd$ = this.navigationEnd$.pipe(shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }));
```

In your constructor for the service you must subscribe to **only** the `lastNavigationEnd$` event. This means that later in your component you can subscribe to it and get the cached most recent end event.

```
// RouterEventsService.ts constructor
this.routerEvents.lastNavigationEnd$.subscribe();   // note: unsubscribe in app.component not needed
```

Then you can use `routerEvents.lastNavigationEnd$` in your component and it will trigger immediately once the component is initialized. You can use it in your constructor, `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterContentInit` etc.

Best to keep both `navigationEnd$` and `lastNavigationEn$` to be explicit if you end up doing this.

Comment: This is a very similar answer to David's, but I'm exposing an actual observable from the service instead of a property. Apart form the triggering 'subscribe' in the service you don't need to subscribe to anything until you need it. You can then use `navigationEndReplay$` as a true observable from your own code. Note: I didn't implement here the pairWise, but I think that's a great idea.

Comment: Simon Weaver, I think you meant add the subscription in the `app.component`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the previous answers I made the following solution:

```js
  import { filter, map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof ActivationStart),
        map(({ snapshot }) => snapshot),
        startWith(this.route.snapshot)
      )
      .subscribe((snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => /** ... do something */ )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've handled my case like this

```
//Whatever I was doing in route.events subcription put it into method and call it onInit()
this.validateRoute(this.router.url);

//Then make subscription to route changes and do it again on each, can do this in constructor or onInit() doesnt matter
this.router.events
  .pipe(
     filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
     map((event) => (event as NavigationEnd).urlAfterRedirects),
     untilDestroyed(this),
   )
   .subscribe((url) => {
      this.validateRoute(url);
   });
```

Answer (score -2):

I just stumbled over the same problem and found the reason for it: The Service subscribing to the Router events was never instanciated by the Dependency Injector, because the Service was not injected at that route.

A Service seems to be only instanciated when it is injected somewhere.

So check your first route if the whole code (not the event) is ever called.