# this.router.events not loading on first time in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the router events to fire the first time the component is loaded?

I am using Angular 8.

I have a deep link that moves to another component. So when I click on the deep link its redirect to the Home page. This happens whenever the computer starts a new session.

So as per my investigation when the app loads for the first time it (this.router.events) returns nothing.

Can anyone please suggest to me regarding it.

Following is my code:-
app.component.ts

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getActivatedRoute();
}
```

```
getActivatedRoute() {
    debugger
    const routerSub$ = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.routes = event.url.toLowerCase().split('/');
        this.currentRoute = this.routes[1];
        if (this.currentRoute !== this.previousRoute) {
          this.setBodyClassBasedOnRouter(this.routes);
          this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please share more code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237318/angular-2-router-event-not-firing-first-time
Hope this would help you

Comment: @LasalSethiya Okay Let me check

Answer (score 24):

The `NavigationEnd` event has already been raised when the component registers for it. best solution would be to use the rxjs `startWith` operator, and let the component load the initial state from the injected Route, like this:

```
const routerSub$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
  startWith(this.router)).
  subscribe((event) => {
        this.routes = event.url.toLowerCase().split('/');
        this.currentRoute = this.routes[1];
        if (this.currentRoute !== this.previousRoute) {
          this.setBodyClassBasedOnRouter(this.routes);
          this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
        }
    });
```

Pay attention to the fact that HTML elements are still not rendered when the constructor is running (if used inside the constructor).

Comment: neat, first time to use startWith

Answer (score 4):

use it in the constructor

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router'; 
class ...   
constructor(private router:Router) {
    
        this.router.events
        .pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
          map((event: NavigationEnd) => event.url))
        .subscribe(url => {
    
          const lastUrlSegment = url.split('?')[0].split('/').pop()
          console.log(lastUrlSegment)
          console.log(url)
        });
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First load working with [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

```
...
constructor(public activatedroute: ActivatedRoute,) {}
... 
this.activatedroute.url.subscribe(data=>{
            ....
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `router.event`. you can just use `router.url` for first loading.

otherwise you can use ActivatedRoute state snapshot url for first time and router event for next routings:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
){
  let activeRoute = this.route['_routerState']['snapshot'].url;
      
  this.routes = activeRoute.toLowerCase().split('/');
  this.currentRoute = this.routes[1];
  if (this.currentRoute !== this.previousRoute) {
    this.setBodyClassBasedOnRouter(this.routes);
    this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
  }

  this.router.events.subscribe({
    next: (rEvent: any) => {
      if(rEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.routes = this.router.url.toLowerCase().split('/');
        this.currentRoute = this.routes[1];
        if (this.currentRoute !== this.previousRoute) {
          this.setBodyClassBasedOnRouter(this.routes);
          this.previousRoute = this.currentRoute;
        }
      }
    }
  )}      
}
```